# Errors with an installed NuGet package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017

First, I develop a program with "Any CPU". 
Setting is "32 bit priority" and Any CPU. because It was default.

after I finish development, No compile error.
then, I switch Platform x64 and re-compile.
VS2017 show lot of error all installed NuGet package.

I tried to remove folder "obj", "bin". but I can not resolve anything. There is 28 errors. All is class name that I installed with NuGet.

SHould I not switch this ?

[image]

Why VS2017 has so many trouble ? Is this normal ?
When I develop with win-form, There is no trouble when I change target x86,x64...

How to resolve this un-linked class ? 
All must be work...

My Nuget package is UwpDesktop, InputSimulator.

**Update 1**: I tried to re-install NuGet. but it does not resolve.

**Update 2**:   I give up to use "x64". but I tried to modify the setting "AnyCPU" for 64 bit. Now, I success to compile again with 64 bit setting. I am also disable to un-check "32bit priority" option too.  but.. I still feel big pain with VS2017 development , haha, It's really.

I compared Project setting with

(A) Any CPU = build success, Output folder is bin\Debug\

(B) x64 in Project setting, Output folder is  bin\x64\Debug\

Both is "same" Except output folder name.
Is it important ??

I can not understand Why VS2017 can not build. 
I think , Main cause is NuGet installed path. I do not know it, because I am 2nd week to learn VS2017, UWP : )

Now, There is still problem, 
If I switch back to "x64", I can not compile..
but I can compile "AnyCPU".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which errors occurred in x64 platform? I have no clue for them, please include the list here.

Comment: Some packages sometimes dont have assemblies for a specific framework and platform in Nuget, try removing the nuget package and adding it again so if it is the case the problem would raise. Provide more info on your error and your setup (framework version, project type, version of the NuGet package installed, etc).

Comment: I updated some progress . thank you !

Comment: What is the build error when you build in x64 platform in output window? Those error messages will help us to know if this error is related to that package.

Comment: Hello Leo. I review my build again and I found solution !     After I install NuGet package, VS2017 only install it into Debug folder. First, I copy all DLL + some files to "Release" folder. and I also has to copy all DLL + some file into "x64/Release" folder too !.   This is solution. Thank you for remind me.  I resolve all.    but My question is Why NuGet do not install DLL files to necessary release folder too ? Is this normal ?

Comment: @KazuhikoNakayama, Generally, NuGet will install the dll to the Debug folder by default, when you change the configuration from Debug to Release, nuget will copy the dll to the release folder. so if you want nuget copy the dll to the release folder, you can change the configuration from debug to release. Since you have resolved you question, you can write your solution as answer, and mark it, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Thank you Tetsuya, Leo, bradbury9 for many hint.

I resolve this issue by my self.

As Leo wrote , Here is solution.

- NuGet will install the dll to the Debug folder by default
- To build with "Release" , We have to copy necessary DLL from "Debug" to "Release".
- and Sometime, We have to copy x64/Release , x86/Release folder too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some manual setup is required for that package. I quote https://preview.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop/10.0.14393.3

"*We are working on updating this package with the latest release. Meanwhile as a workaround please add the following winmds to your project...*"

Perhaps you want to downgrade that package and install a previous version, or follow those steps to be able to use it.

Comment: @KazuhikoNakayama I agree on NuGet being a cool tool, but you can force a specific package version using the NuGet console.  `Install-Package [PackageName] -Version [VersionToInstall]`